# Return Postman error message to user on failed login/reg React-Native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

[image]

[image]

My backend is set up with validations, which I want to return to the user on failed attempts.The top picture is what I am currently returning. The picture below that one (what my postman returns) is one such error message I want to return to a user on a failed login attempt in my try/catch block. I would prefer to do this via the Alert.alert() method. The following is my loginUser code:

```
enter code hexport interface LoginRequest {
 name: string;
 pass: string;
}

export const loginUser = async (
  request: LoginRequest,
  onSuccess: (user: User) => void,
  onError: (error: any) => void,
) => {
  console.log(request);

try {
  await logout();

const loginResponse: AxiosResponse<LoginResponse> = await login(request);

const loginResponseData: LoginResponse = loginResponse.data;
console.log('userAuth: ', loginResponseData);

await AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token', loginResponseData.access_token);
await AsyncStorage.setItem('logout_token', loginResponseData.logout_token);
await AsyncStorage.setItem('csrf_token', loginResponseData.csrf_token);

const userId = loginResponseData.current_user.uid;
const userResponse: AxiosResponse<User> = await getUser(userId);
console.log('user response:', userResponse);
onSuccess(userResponse.data);
} catch (error: any) {
  console.log('Login error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
  console.log();
  onError(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Checkout these [Axios Docs -Handle errors](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors).

Comment: you can check for error.response.data like in axios docs, and pass it inside onError()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the body of the response of an Axios 4xx error with `error.response.data`. Simply use the below line:

```js
onError(error?.response?.data?.message || error);
```